# Limit of trigonometric function: $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan2x}x$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Find $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\tan2x}x$

I change tan to sin/cos , we have $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\sin2x}{x\cos2x}$

Using  l'Hopital's rule,

I get $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac {\cos2x}{(x)(-\sin2x)(\cos2x)}$ = $\lim_{x\to 0} -\frac {1}{(x)(\sin2x)}$

I can't proceed with l'Hopital's rule anymore here as I get 1/0.

Comment: You did not compute the denominator right. Try to pull the $\cos 2x$ out first as its limit is 1 and then use l'Hospital's rule.

Comment: If you want to apply L'Hospital don't apply it to the whole expression, use it only to compute $\lim \frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$. Compute separatedly the limit of the cosine and use $\lim(fg)=\lim f\lim g$. Alternatively write $\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}=2\frac{\sin(2x)}{2x}$ and use that $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=1$.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

$$\frac{\tan2x}x=2\cdot\frac{\sin2x}{2x}\cdot\frac1{\cos2x}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Alternatively, after pulling out $ \cos 2 x $ as its limit is $1$, the formula of duplication of the sine does the job.